# Can I mix PHP with other scripting language?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js

I made a NGO website that has customer service in it, means that clients are able to chat directly to the admin. I've built 30% of it with PHP. But, I thought it's difficult to make a chat application with PHP. I've been told that Node.js is the best web development to make chat application. Can I mix PHP with Node.js ?

Comment: From inside the php script you can run any sort of commands to different programming languages, i.e.: `$rubyOutput = shell_execute("ruby somescript.rb")`

Comment: Is that good implementation ? Pedro Lobito

Comment: I wouldn't say "good" but it's possible ;)

Comment: Why could you not write the thing in php/ajax? I think there are existing plug in out there

Answer (score 2):

Generally, people name files depending on what language the code inside is written in.  For example, the `.php` extension is run by a PHP interpreter. Certain files can have other languages mixed in. For example, a `.html` file can contain CSS and Javascript. Another example is the `.html.erb` extension in a Rails app, which can contains both Ruby and HTML/CSS/JS code. This is accomplished by something known as a *preprocessor*.

You could use a preprocessor to mix mostly any language together, but I'm not sure that will make your life any easier making an app. It's probably a better idea to separate your app into *microcomponents*, which can all be written in different languages.

For example, a chat server could be written in Node and a REST API written in Rails. They might be hosted on separate servers and communicate with each other by sending HTTP requests.

As far as Node being "the best" for making a chat server, that's a totally subjective point and StackOverflow discourages opinion-based conjectures.

It's also worth considering whether an open-source chat project could be integrated with your existing code. I.e. something already made.

Comment: Ohh okay. I will learn how to implementation micro-components in web application.. Thanks for the answer.